# Pass data from Rad Parent Window to Child Window

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, radwindow

I have a rad window, that user can add few items to the grid [For an Example : Stationary]. Once User need to remove item, I want to popup a rad window which request User Name Password and Redirect to Another page to remove item. Only Some users are allowed to remove items. So my question is how to pass that Grid data from Parent Window to Child window.?  [I am saving grid data on ViewState]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution for this

http://webapps-in-action.com/post/How-to-use-a-Telerik-RadWindow-(Modal)-with-independent-IFrame-to-load-collect-validate-user-data

[Source Code Download](https://webapps.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#TelerikModalWindow/)